# Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '44,052,037.79'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point

Hello im getting "ValueError: could not convert string to float: " error in python I know what this error means but i cant fix it... i have converted string to float but getting same error anyone can help me ?

```
    #CAKE POOL
    cake_pool = '0x73feaa1ee314f8c655e354234017be2193c9e24e'
    cake_staked_url = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82&address=" + cake_pool + "&tag=latest"
    response = requests.get(cake_staked_url)
    cakeurl = response.json()
    staked_cake = float(cakeurl['result']) / 1000000000000000000
    staked_cake = float(staked_cake)  <---- converted string to float
    print(type(staked_cake) , str(staked_cake)) <--- result 'float'
    staked_cake = '{0:,.2f}'.format(float(staked_cake))
    print("CAKE POOL: " + str(staked_cake) + " CAKE STAKED")
    #END OF CAKE POOL

    #BNB POOL
    bnb_pool = '0x326D754c64329aD7cb35744770D56D0E1f3B3124'
    bnb_staked_url = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82&address=" + bnb_pool + "&tag=latest"
    response = requests.get(bnb_staked_url)
    bnburl = response.json()
    staked_bnb = float(bnburl['result']) / 1000000000000000000
    staked_bnb = float(staked_bnb) <---- converted string to float
    print(type(staked_bnb), staked_bnb) <--- result 'float'
    print(staked_bnb)
    total = float(staked_cake) + float(staked_bnb) <---- i want to sum 'staked_cake' and 'staked_bnb' but getting error
    print(total)
    staked_bnb = '{0:,.2f}'.format(float(staked_bnb))
    print("BNB POOL: " + staked_bnb + " CAKE STAKED")
    #END OF BNB POOL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED :D

```
staked_cake = '{0:,.2f}'.format(float(staked_cake))
```

This is why i was getting error message :D

Answer (score 0):

Print each of your strings and check if you can convert them to float or not. I'm sure you would find ones that you can't. Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: Thanks budd I already fixed it... i was converting string > float > string on line 9 :D